# AzureDevOps: How to restrict users from seeing other users in an organization

Tags: azure-devops

In order to get a complete view over all of my customer projects, I want to invite all customer in one DevOps organization. Naturally, the individual customer should not be able which other customers are in the organization. Although I am able to restrict users on the project level, they are still able to see every user on the organization level. Is it possible to restrict the access to any organization level information such as the user list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by adding people to "Project-Scoped Users" group on Orga-Level. As the group info describes: "Members of this group will have limited visibility to organization-level data"

Means they will not see Userstab, Billing and so on.

Here are also some links to the topic :) https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users.md#restrict-user-view-to-organization-projects

or look here: https://dev.to/n3wt0n/azure-devops-limit-user-visibility-and-collaboration-to-specific-projects-2mgg

Comment: Yes! Overread first and added the users to the "Project-Valid Users" Group.